# Locked Motor - Can it be fixed without replacing the engine?

Tags: engine, oil

First of all, I WILL APOLOGIZE if I get too lengthy.

Drove the car, parked and was away from it for about 10 minutes. When I tried to start it, lots of lights came on and went off right away but wouldn't start. It made me think it needed a jump so I put my charger on for 15-20 minutes and nothing.

I turned off the car and I noticed that the light on the light switch was flashing and clicking. I put my foot on the break and it stopped! I turned off the lights with the switch and the amber lights wouldn't go off. I just unhooked the battery so as I could go on my way with my daughter and to worry about this tomorrow.

My son-n-law looked puzzled when I told him that the car was not making any noise, NO oil lamp light on and was running fine then he said hum, it might be the starter so I bought one and he put it on. Not the problem, but now he said the car was bone dry of oil! That seemed weird because I had just checked it within the last week and it was fine. I am 64 years old and I've never run a car out of oil. He said all he could do is try to turn the engine by hand to see if it is locked up. Done and he could not move the gear but a little and not all the way around which he said he would have to do. He did this without putting oil in the car! The other thing I want to add is that the cars oil was pretty black when I checked it. I checked the oil myself the next morning and it showed 3/4 of an inch on the stick.

No harm in putting Marvel Mystery Oil and/or Kroil and let it sit two or three days and give it another try?

No harm in trying since he said it was a lost cause, right?

Comment: Welcome to the site, great detail, but we could use the year make and model of the car! Also if the engine was seized the starter would at least try to engage, this sounds like an electrical problem to me.

Comment: Can you give a make model and year for your vehicle?

Comment: Pull the spark plugs and put in about 1oz of marvel oil in each cylinder, let set overnight, reinstall plugs, see if it will turn over now.

Comment: Sorry! I guess a description would help, huh?  It's a 2009 Ford Fusion 3.0L V6

Comment: He said it was bone dry, but there's 3/4 of an inch of oil on the stick? Which is it?

Comment: MooseLucifer was right!  It was a very, very, very bad battery. I decided to take Moab's advice too. What oil that was on the stick that I saw was very, very, very dirty. I used the Marvell oil and followed your instructions.  Started right up!  I'm pleased and thankful for your experienced help. David is the one who commented on the 12th and made me realize that I had not followed up with feedback!  THANKS ONCE AGAIN